# How to send Map in request parameters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I ran into a problem, I have a request with parameters in the Map<String, String> apiKeyMap variable, I want to add more parameters that are in the `FilterStationParamsModel` using the `toJson()` method, but I get an error when adding one map to another. Tell me how to solve the problem so that parameters are added from the model?

**FilterStationParamsModel**

```
class FilterStationParamsModel {
  int? limit;
  int? offset;

  FilterStationParamsModel({
    this.limit,
    this.offset,
  });

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    return {
      'limit': '123123',
      'offset': '123123',
    };
  }
}
```

**request**

```
  @override
  Future<List<MainModel>> get({
    FilterStationParamsModel? filterStationParamsModel,
  }) async {
    final apiKeyMap = await ApiKey.getCryptoApiKeyMap();
    apiKeyMap!
        .addAll({filterStationParamsModel!.toJson()} as Map<String, String>);
    const String url = '/user';
    final response = await _helper.get(url: url, queryParameters: apiKeyMap);

    final data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List;
    return data
        .map((json) => MainModel.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }
```

**error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterStationParamsModel!.toJson()` is already returning map you can directly use it>

```dart
 apiKeyMap!
        .addAll(filterStationParamsModel!.toJson());
```

If you like to separate key for the model, you can do

```dart
 apiKeyMap!.addAll({"apiKeyMap": filterStationParamsModel!.toJson()});
```